# angular2 ngIf true or false condition

Tags: javascript, angular

Can someone help me with this `ngIf` condition, I'm trying to hide the logout when key doesn't exist and show it when its exist in the `localStorage`. I'm getting confused about multiple conditions in the `ngIf` but the checks are correct.

This check is being used as a directive.

```
checkSession() {
  var checkKey = localStorage.getItem('sessionKey');
  if(checkKey == null){
      var showLogout = false;
      console.log('null key: ', checkKey);
  } else {
      showLogout = true;
      //this check will only be available once the user is logged in
      console.log('key exist: ' checkKey);
  }

}
```

Html

```
 <a (click)="logout()" title="Logout" *ngIf="showLogout || (!showLogout && !showLogout)">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems what you want is

```
export class MyComponent {

  /// other stuff

  showLogout:boolean = false;

  checkSession() {
    var checkKey = localStorage.getItem('sessionKey');
    if(checkKey == null){
        this.showLogout = false; // changed
        console.log('null key: ', checkKey);
    } else {
        this.showLogout = true; // changed
        //this check will only be available once the user is logged in
        console.log('key exist: ' checkKey);
    }
  }
}
```

A local variable won't be available in the template. The template can only access top-level properties and methods of your components class directly.

Comment: I see, even if the html line is also in the component not as an external template? But the check in the html is correct? just need to add this.showLogout insteadd?

Comment: If the template is added as `template: "..."` or `templateUrl: "pathToTemplate"` doesn't make any difference. If you declare a variable local to your method (`checkSession`) the variable won't exist anymore if executing the method is completed.

Comment: I didn't even look so far as to your `*ngIf`. Just `*ngIf="showLogout"` or `*ngIf="!showLogout"` is enough depending on what exactly you want. You can set a default value for `this.showLogout` (I update my answer for that).

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah that make sense now. I've added the boolean part as well but I thought that's default to false but I guess not.

Comment: Default is `null` but `*ngIf` treats `null` as falsy, therefore you can omit setting it to `false` explicitly.